# FFMPEG video cropping is too slow

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using [WritingMinds](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library to execute this ffmpeg command:

```
-y -i /data/user/0/ae.alphaapps.rombeye/cache/1527414847451.mp4 -vf crop=720:880:0:196 -threads 16 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy /storage/emulated/0/.temp/15274148557981952135171779784555.mp4
```

my main goal is to crop a 720p resolution video as fast as possible, but it's taking about 6 minutes for a 5 minutes video.
Is it normal at this rate? and would it be any way to make it faster?
Is there any other solution that make video cropping faster?

Comment: WritingMinds has you compile x264 with `--disable-asm` which can result in a significant slowdown. Remove this and re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg is kind of slow on android as it doesn't have hardware acceleration on android. You can try out other ffmpeg options like controlling crf and bitrate to get performance speed over quality.